# Installing driver for Netgear WNA1100 WiFi Adapter - Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: wireless, server, drivers, netgear

I recently purchased the WNA1100 WiFi Adapter for my Ubuntu Server 12.04 Box. Since I'm new to Ubuntu, I'm unable to install the drivers for the WiFi Adapter. I found that the WiFi adapter uses the Atheros AR9271 chipset. I downloaded the `htc_9271.fw` file from the [Linux Wireless site](http://linuxwireless.org/download/htc_fw/1.3/).

How do I install the driver?

Answer (score 3):

You may need both files there; htc_9271.fw and htc_7010.fw. Both are mentioned in:

```
    modinfo ath9k_htc
```

Please open at terminal and do:

```
    cd Desktop   <--or wherever the downloaded files are
    sudo cp htc_9271.fw /lib/firmware
    sudo cp htc_7010.fw /lib/firmware
```

Now unload and reload the driver:

```
    sudo modprobe -r ath9k_htc && sudo modprobe ath9k_htc
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you return the card and purchase something that's already supported:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported

You are probably used to wrestling with driver annoyances in Windows and therefore think it's pretty normal.  In Linux, it isn't.  If you have to wrestle with drivers, it's because your card isn't actually supported - you may be able to get it to work, but you're usually better off just returning it and getting something that IS supported, which will "just work" without needing to fight with it.

Comment: NO! It is supported, see:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsNetgear#USB

The WNA1100 is supported by the Atheros driver & firmware under Linux.

Comment: you realize you replied to a nearly three year old answer, right?  at the time OP posted his or her question, that was unsupported hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Just unplug and plug back your usb adapter.

This worked for me after reconnecting the device!

Comment: But you didn't need to install any driver? Because this isn't *plug&play*

Answer (score 0):

This was not working for me and I was banging my head against wall. Until I run apt-get update && apt-get upgrade.

The recent upgrade solved the issue, and the card is working with charm.

Ubuntu: 13.04 
Kernel: 3.8.0-30-generic #44-Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour à Toutes et à Tous.

Merci pour les efforts, l'altruisme et la sympathie
avec laquelle vous apportez de l'aide aux besogneux de la
communauté UBUNTU.

Mon problème était le suivant :
ma Clé USB Netgear WNA1100 N150 Wifi ne fonctionnait
pas sur UBUNTU 16.04 LTS.

Solution :

1 - j'ai téléchargé **ath9k_htc-installer_1-0-4.deb**

2 - Dans le dossier Télécharger, clique droit sur le nom du paquet, 
    puis Ouvrir avec installation de l'application.

Resultat : ça marche.

Encore merci.

Comment: Salut, est-ce que tu peux ré-écrire ta réponse en anglais s'il te plait? Could you please rewrite your answer in english please?

Answer (score -1):

@Jim Salter
If you check the site you gave you will find that Netgear WNA 1100 is supported:

"WNA1100

Atheros

ath9k_htc

Need only a .deb packet

Download the last version of the http://sourceforge.net/projects/ath9...htc-installer/ and execute the .deb packet. Connect the WiFi adapter"