# How to get NETGEAR - N150 Wireless USB Adapter WNA1100 working on Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, usb-modem, adapter, netgear

I do have Netgear - N150 Wireless USB Adapter WNA1100. How can I connect this to Ubuntu OS?
Please help me to make it working

Comment: You may need a compatible driver for your Network interface card (NIC). Answer from a newby.

Comment: have a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/216066/installing-driver-for-netgear-wna1100-wifi-adapter-ubuntu-server-12-04